# QT display image obtained from network access manager

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qnetworkaccessmanager, qtnetwork

I am trying to display the image obtained from the get request made using networkaccess manager. I am able to compile and even able to run it. but I am unable to show the image in a Qlabel.

```
QNetworkAccessManager* nam;

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    nam = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    QUrl url("http://i.imgur.com/Uw7Fk.jpg");
    QNetworkReply* reply = nam->get(QNetworkRequest(url));
    if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError)
    {
        QImageReader imageReader(reply);
        imageReader.setAutoDetectImageFormat (false);
        QImage pic = imageReader.read();
        ui->label_2->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(pic));

     }


}
```

Please tell me where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The data in `QNetworkReply` is not ready immediately after the call to `QNetworkAccessManager::get()`. The call is asynchronous, and you need to connect to either the `finished()` signal of QNetworkAccessManager, or `readyRead()` signal of QNetworkReply before you attempt to retrieve any data.

Answer (score 0):

To get image synchronously, you can use QEventLoop like below:

```
QNetworkAccessManager* nam;

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    nam = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    QUrl url("http://i.imgur.com/Uw7Fk.jpg");
    QNetworkReply* reply = nam->get(QNetworkRequest(url));

    QEventLoop eventloop;
    connect(reply,SIGNAL(finished()),&eventloop,SLOT(quit()));
    eventLoop.exec();

    if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError)
    {
        QImageReader imageReader(reply);
        imageReader.setAutoDetectImageFormat (false);
        QImage pic = imageReader.read();
        ui->label_2->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(pic));

     }


}
```